# In aisleriot solitaire on Ubuntu, the Gnomangelo card face images have become fragmented

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.  Yesterday, all of a sudden, the card faces in aisleriot have become corrupt.  The cards are still recognizable, with the number in the top left of the card still being there and of the right color, but the rest of the card is hit or miss (see screenshot).[image: Screenshot of Freecell game].  I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the card deck, but there was no difference:

```sh
sudo apt-get install -y gnome-cards-data
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnome-cards-data is already the newest version (1:3.22.5-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest librsvg update today fixed that problem for me.